# ASP.NET Core measure performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to measure the performance in my ASP.NET Core application. More specific, the time necessary for a single HTTP request to complete.

The way I am doing this right now is using [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) instances around my code:

- Deserialization ([Custom JsonConverter, Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm))
- Running the job for the received request
- Serialization ([Custom JsonConverter, Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm))

and return the result to stdout.

**EDIT**

As you can imagine, this approach spreads around the different application parts while it would be better to have it isolated (e.g. separate class) where it would be easier to maintain.

What is the best way to measure performance in a ASP.NET Core application?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close since this asking for recommendations _is_ off topic here. In the interests of conversation: have you looked at any of the pre-built performance monitoring tools aimed at ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Hi @john, thanks for the reply but I am not sure I understand your point: as stated in my question, I am seeking the most elegant way to measure performance of HTTP requests in ASP.NET Core as it does not seem the framework provides that out of the box.

Comment: Maybe https://www.nuget.org/packages/Net.CrossCutting.RequestLogger/ helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an ActionLogFilter using the [asp.net filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).

```
    public class ActionLogFilter : IActionFilter
{
    // some dependencies
    private DateTime traceStart;
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch;

    public ActionLogFilter(// some dependencies)
    {
        this.stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    // here the action starts executing
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        this.traceStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.stopwatch.Start();
    }

    // here the action is executed
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        this.stopwatch.Stop();
        var traceEnd = this.traceStart
                       .AddMilliseconds(this.stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        // do something, persist it somewhere if necessary
    }
}
```

Now you can go ahead to your startup class and add register the filter

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
   .....
   services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(ActionLogFilter));
   .....
}
```

If you need more informations within that action log filter, for instance about the request controller, path and so on, you can register [IHttpContextAccesor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.0) with your favourite IoC-Container. For native DI do the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
   .....
   services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccesor>();
   .....
}
```

You can then inject the dependency into the filter and access the HttpContext via a [property of the IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.0) instance.

If you want that filter to run async, you could implement [IAsyncActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) instead.